# Which versions of eclipse support IBM Websphere 6.1?

Tags: eclipse, version, websphere-6.1

I tried to install Websphere 6.1 plugins in Eclipse Luna 4.4 version, but couldn't find it in the Marketplace. 
May I know which versions of eclipse support IBM Websphere 6.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSphere Application Server version 6.1 has been out of service since 9/30/2013, you should move to an in-service version for support.

Comment: You mean to say the Websphere 6.1 version is out of service?

Comment: Yes.  7.0 is the current oldest version in service, and both 7.0 and 8.0 go out of service at the end of April.